# Redirecting to homepage after add to cart

Tags: cart, error, addtocart, redirect, home-page

I'm having issues that when you add a product to the cart, it automatically redirects to the homepage. I have tried switching it to redirect to cart as well, but it still redirects to the homepage.

I would like it to just add to cart and stay on the same page. Any ideas how to resolve this

For example if you add any of these products to the cart you will see

https://mellcrest.com/bathroom/accessories/bath-mats.html

Comment: It seems like something is wrong with your code during add to cart because it redirecting 301 to homepage.
Check your log file or Please disable module which use add to cart event observer and than test to debug

Comment: I have no idea how to do that, Could you help me out im new to magento

Comment: Sure It would be my pleasure, But I need to debug your website to resolve issue

Comment: Ok, do you want to email me? garry@mellcrest.com Thank you so much

Comment: I sent you an email.. Please check

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's usually a bit hard to debug things like this, but from the redirect urls your webserver is giving back I think it's your web server rewrites that are the issue. I think with your current configuration Magento is confused between using `/index.php/` including urls and not using them.

It's possible that following this stackoverflow answer will help you solve that issue (and likely more, incl. SEO ones):

> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10474740/how-to-remove-index-php-from-urls

I should also note, although a bit off-topic for the specific answer, that while you are also running a rather unpatched version of magento which exposes you to security risks, you are also running a misconfigured Apache server that exposes your var folder in a way where it makes you susceptible to the cacheleak vulnerability.

I hope this resolves your issue.

Comment: Thank you I will try this tomorrow, the problem occurred somewhere installing the ssl cert or moving the domain name. As was another domain name hoteltradesuppliers.com was switched to mellcrest .com yesterday.

Comment: When you say unpatched what do you mean? I updated the site yesterday to latest version. What else should I be doing to it ? Is there a guide for this and how can I configure apache better ?:

Comment: @GarrySpight Do let me know if my advice worked out for you. Also, in regards to your store, I shot you an email because it falls quite a bit outside the scope of your original question to have this discussion here.

Comment: Thank you Dimitris, I got your email and will go through it tomorrow. I will let you know how it all goes

Comment: @GarrySpight Great!

Comment: I'm new to this so a sharp learning curve for me.

Comment: Right I have narrowed this down to a rewrite issue that was caused by the https, Is I have a few rewrites in my htaccess file as it has a multi store front on the site.

Comment: @GarrySpight Good to hear you figured it out :-) Feel free to answer your own question and accept it as the answer if this answer doesn't cover it, so it's marked as resolved